Why can't I securely store an auth0 JWT token locally?
I use Auth0 in a React app. By default, auth tokens are stored in memory and and have be re-fetched on a browser reload. This causes a noticeable delay when reloading the page, particularly when the wifi isn't great.
I can store these in local storage with the cacheLocation='localstorage' option, and when I do so the app feels much faster. Unfortunately, storing the tokens locally increases the risk from XSS attacks and is not recommended in production.
I don't want to compromise security for performance. But is it really impossible to persist these tokens locally in a secure way? What about web workers? IndexedDB? Could the tokens be encrypted with an in-memory secret key? etc. Is there no hope for a better solution here?

As far as I know, Web Workers can be used to perform background tasks but they don't provide a secure storage mechanism themselves. IndexedDB is a more secure alternative to localStorage as it allows for an asynchronous API . However, it still doesn't protect against XSS attacks. (IndexedDB operates under the same-origin policy, meaning that if an attacker can inject a script into your site through an XSS vulnerability, they can also access your IndexedDB storage.)

Encrypting tokens before storing them in localStorage or IndexedDB is an option. You can use an in-memory secret key to encrypt and decrypt the tokens.
Storing tokens in secure, HttpOnly cookies can be a better approach as they are not accessible via JavaScript, thus reducing the risk of XSS attacks. You can configure the cookies to be accessible only over HTTPS and set them to be HttpOnly.

